# Loading images in collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous, uicollectionview

Each `UITableViewCell` contains a `UICollectionView`. Having trouble figuring out why some `UICollectionViewCell` images are not showing up. I'm using `SDWebImage` library to load images. The method `- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url`calls `[self sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad];`. I think cancelling the previous request is the problem, but read somewhere that will create a race condition. Problem doesnt happen for every `UITableViewCell`, and if I tap on cell for details and go back, the images fill in. Perhaps I need to reload data somewhere. Any tips on how to solve this?
[image]

Comment: You will have to reload `collectionView` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of `tableView`.

Answer (score 1):

**if you try to image fatch from server to try this.**

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NewProfileCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


[cell.img_user_image sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[mutDict valueForKey:@"UserImageURL"][indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"No_IMAGE_PLACE"]];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [self.imageView cancelCurrentImageLoad];
    [self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // Placeholder image
}
```